# Find email source of all generated email by SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, email, subscriptions

I was recently informed by MS exchange team in our company that SP is sending email to few old addresses (not exists anymore) of our organisation. They can see that these emails are coming from SP. These emails are probably generated from different places (site / lists). Is there anyway i can find each email source. i have recipient email address.

in-short i need to identify all the subscription of a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rahil,

The best solution to capture all outgoing emails from SharePoint is to set up SMTP in IIS and activate logging. You're probably pointing to your exchange server directly, so you don't have the option to log.

This will at least tell you what emails are going out, so you can track down more info.

Here's the steps you need to follow:

[Setting up the IIS SMTP Server for Sending Email from SharePoint 2010 on Server 2008 R2](https://blog.sharepointrx.com/2010/11/18/setting-up-the-iis-smtp-server-for-sending-email-from-sharepoint-2010-on-server-2008-r2/)

[How To Check SMTP Logs in Windows Server (IIS)](http://www.winservermart.com/HowTo/SMTP_Logs.aspx)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Jim

Answer (score 4):

1. **Alerts - OOTB method**

   To view alerts for other people, you must be a site owner.

   - Click the Site Actions menu and then click Site Settings.
   - On the Site Settings page, under Site Administration, click User alerts.
   - In the list next to Display alerts for, select the person whose alerts you want to view.
   - Click the Update button.
2. **Event Receiver - Custom Solution** - Check all solutions deployed in farm, to check the SendMail api being used
3. **SPD Workflow - OOTB method** - Check all SPD workflows for email steps. It will be attached on item created / updated.
4. **Timer Job - Custom solution** - Check all custom timer job deployed on Farm to see for SendMail api in the code
5. **Custom solution** - Check for any other type of custom solution deployed on farm,